# Getting null pointer exception in JDBC(mySql) program

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I checked everything like username, password, db_url, table name, etc but still I get this output---connecting to database
creating statement
java.lang.NullPointerException

here is my code, (I'm using eclipse Kepler EE and MySQL 5.6.17.0)

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Demo {
static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sample";
static final String USER="root" ;
static final String PASS="root";
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    try
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("connecting to database");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("creating statement");
        String sql="select * from sample";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            int eid=rs.getInt("id");
            String ename=rs.getString("name");
            System.out.print(eid+"\t");
            System.out.print(ename);
            System.out.println("");

        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(stmt!=null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        try
        {
            if(conn!=null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) `stmt` is null..2) In your `DB_URL`, you have not specified any port no

Answer (score 0):

You didnt create `stmt` object

```
stmt = conn.createStatement( );
```

You have to add above line before this line `ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);`

You are executing query on a `null` object.
So getting NPE

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your statement is set. It is always null.

I think you should use this:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement( );
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `Statement stmt=null;` and you never initialize it later.